# translate scss to css in ruby cmd for writing sass code

Tags: ruby

i have faced this problem

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - D:\Tasks\Bootstrap
  Use --trace for backtrace.

after i have write this command in ruby cmd:

```
sass D:\Tasks\Bootstrap 4\css\style.scss D:\Tasks\Bootstrap 4\compiledcss\style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got spaces in your path and the shell is breaking the arguments on spaces, so either eliminate those or quote each path:

```
sass "D:\Tasks\Bootstrap 4\css\style.scss" "D:\Tasks\Bootstrap 4\compiledcss\style.css"
```

Spaces in filenames are super annoying, so they're best avoided if you can.